# Receiving error message Bad state: No element

Tags: flutter

I am getting the following error message Bad state: No element

On investigation I found out that the notificationId is not flowing from one page to another.

Hence if you could please help me resolve this issue.

Let me know if you require anymore information from my end.

Please find below code :

notification.dart

```
class NotificationList extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'notification-list';

  void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx, int id, String title) {
    print(id);
    print(title);
    // id and title data flowing till here
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
      NotificationDetail.routeName,
      arguments: {
        'notificationId': id,
        'Title': title,
      },
    );
  }
```

main.dart

```
 initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (ctx) => LoginMainPage(),
          NotificationList.routeName: (ctx) => NotificationList(),
          NotificationDetail.routeName: (ctx) => NotificationDetail(),
        },
      ),
```

notificationDetail.dart

```
class NotificationDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'notification-detail';

  @override
  _NotificationDetailState createState() => _NotificationDetailState();
}

class _NotificationDetailState extends State<NotificationDetail> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final notificationId = args['notificationId'];
    print(notificationId); //notificationId is coming as null
    final loadednotification =
        Provider.of<NotificationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .findByNotificationId(notificationId);
    print(loadednotification.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "args['notificationId']" will be  "args['Id'];"?

Comment: apologies there was a typo in the code ...but the issue still persists